# Statistics of sample correlation for uniformly distributed samples

Tags: correlation, matlab, uniform-distribution

I am computing the sample correlation between two vectors of uncorrelated and uniformly distributed samples using MATLAB. More precisely, I compute
$$
r_N=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N x_{i}\, y_{i},
$$ 
where $E(X)=E(Y)={\rm cov}(X,Y)=0$, and $x_{i}, y_{i}$ are drawn from a uniform distribution in $[-A/2,A/2]$. 
It is clear that $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} r_N=0$. However, I would like to compute an estimate of $\tilde{N}$ such that, given $\epsilon >0$ and $\alpha >0$, we have $ {\rm Pr}(|r_N| < \epsilon) < \alpha$ for all $ N > \tilde{N}$.

In other words, I need an expression for the sample statistic $r_N$. I formulated this question for uniformly distributed data; however I'm interested to know what happens for other distributions (say normal).

Any ideas?

Comment: Since $x$ and $y$ have zero mean $r_N$ has the same expression of $r_{xy}$ in [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation) minus the normalization by the sample standard deviations so I'm not sure about why you don't see the correlation @COOLSerdash.

Comment: You're looking at sampling error.  Watch what happens when you increase $N$ to $10^6$, then $10^7$, then $10^8$, etc.

Comment: I see your point @whuber. So my question now is: is there a way to estimate $N$ such that $P(\left|r_N\right|<\epsilon)>p$ ?

Comment: Yes, there are several ways. Why don't you edit your question to ask this more refined version about estimating $N$?

Comment: Done, should more clear now

Comment: It's not clear that $\lim_{N\to\infty} r_N = 0$. Indeed, $r_N$ is an estimator of ${\rm E}(XY)$, and ${\rm E}(XY) = {\rm cov}(X, Y)$ since ${\rm E}(X)={\rm E}(X)=0$. So, if ${\rm cov}(X, Y) \neq 0$ then $\lim_{N\to\infty} r_N \neq 0$. This implies that $\tilde{N}$ might not exist. Is the covariance/correlation between $X$ and $Y$ supposed to be zero?

Comment: Yes, I assume that ${\rm cov}(X,Y)=0$ so I added that to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is indeed asking for the finite sample distribution
of $r_{N}$. To address your question, let me rephrase it in terms
of linear regressions. So a linkage between $r_{N}$ and the ordinary
least square (OLS) estimator could be highlighted. You observe two
variables $\left\{ x_{i}\right\} _{i=1}^{N}$ and $\left\{ y_{i}\right\} _{i=1}^{N}$,
and they are uncorrelated. Suppose you run a linear regression between
$y_{i}$ and $x_{i}$,
$$
y_{i}=\beta x_{i}+u_{i},\quad i=1,\ldots,N.
$$
Since $y_{i}$ and $x_{i}$ are uncorrelated, the true value $\beta$
is $0$. Note that the OLS estimator of $\beta$ is
$$
\hat{\beta}_{N}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_{i}y_{i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_{i}x_{i}}=\frac{N^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_{i}y_{i}}{N^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_{i}x_{i}}.
$$
Here the numerator of $\hat{\beta}_{N}$ is your $r_{N}$. I did not
impose any distribution assumptions about $x_{i}$ and $y_{i}$, so
no loss of generality was incurred. Based on this linkage, we may
approach your question by using the distribution of $\hat{\beta}_{N}$.
However, it is well known that the finite sample distribution of $\hat{\beta}_{N}$
is not available in most cases. Consequently, my conclusion is pessimistic
in that the 'exact' answer to your question might not exist in most
cases. But an approximate $\tilde{N}$ can be easily found since $\hat{\beta}_{N}$
is asymptotically normal.

First, consider a finite sample case. If $\left\{ x_{i}\right\} _{i=1}^{N}$ is fixed in your experiment,
and $\left\{ y_{i}\right\} _{i=1}^{N}$ are i.i.d. normal with mean
$0$ and variance $\sigma^{2}$. Then it is well known that
$$
\hat{\beta}_{N}\mid x_{1},\ldots,x_{N}\sim N\left(\beta,\frac{\sigma^{2}}{N}\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_{i}^{2}}{N}\right)^{-1}\right).
$$
Consequently,
$$
r_{N}\mid x_{1},\ldots,x_{N}\sim N\left(0,\frac{\sigma^{2}}{N}\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_{i}^{2}}{N}\right)\right).
$$
Denote $\sigma_{r,N}^{2}=\left(\sigma^{2}/N\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_{i}^{2}/N\right)$,
and note that $\sigma_{r,N}$ is monotone decreasing with respect
to $N$. Then given $\varepsilon$, we have $\Pr\left(\left|r_{N}\right|<\varepsilon\right)=1-2\Phi\left(-\varepsilon/\sigma_{r,N}\right)$.
By letting $ $$1-2\Phi\left(-\varepsilon/\sigma_{r,N}\right)=\alpha$,
you can solve $\tilde{N}$. (Remark: I think you are asking for such
a $\tilde{N}$ that $\Pr\left(\left|r_{N}\right|<\varepsilon\right)\geq\alpha$
for all $N>\tilde{N}$.) But these arguments are based on the properties
of normal distributions.

Next, consider the large sample case ($N\rightarrow \infty$), where $x_i$ could be random. Suppose $\left\{ x_{i}\right\} _{i=1}^{N}$ and $\left\{ y_{i}\right\} _{i=1}^{N}$
satisfy the regularity conditions of the LLN and CLT. Asymptotically,
we have
$$
\hat{\beta}_{N}\rightarrow_{d}N\left(\beta,\frac{\sigma^{2}}{N}Q^{-1}\right),\quad Q=\mathrm{{plim}}_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_{i}^{2}}{N},
$$
where $\sigma^{2}$ is the variance of $y_{i}$. By Slutsky lemma,
we have
$$
r_{N}\rightarrow_{d}N\left(0,\frac{\sigma^{2}}{N}Q\right).
$$
It is obvious that $\sigma_{r,N}^{2}$ is a consistent estimator of
$\left(\sigma^{2}/N\right)Q$. Then an approximate $\tilde{N}$ can
be found in the same way.

Comment: You seem to assume that the $x_i$ are not random: I cannot find any place where you either justify or relax the assumption that "$\{x_i\}_{i=1}^N$ is fixed in your experiment." Wouldn't it be simpler (and more accurate) just to compute the mean and variance of $Z = XY$ and apply the CLT directly to it? Incidentally, closed-form analytical solutions for the distribution of $r_N$ can be found when the $x_i$ and $y_i$ have Normal distributions ($|XY|$ then has a Bessel(0) distribution).

Comment: I did not assume $x_i$ are nonrandom in the large sample case. But I did assume that $x_i$ are nonrandom in the finite sample case. I should mention this. Let me edit the post a little bit. I am sure you would get the solution by applying the CLT directly to $XY$.